# Second case runs after criteria's met w/ JS switch case

Tags: javascript, node.js

(This is a "share-my-knowledge" Q&A.)

I created this switch statement to decide what recovery to propose.

```js
  const numPomodoros = 3; 
  switch (0) {
    case numPomodoros % 3:
      console.log('I propose coffee, V8, and 5m of yoga.');
    case numPomodoros % 4:
      console.log('I propose a 20m nap.');
  }
```

I expected only the first case to run (3 % 3 === 0, should run; 4 % 3 === 1, should not run); however, the second case always runs:

```
$ node index.js s
I propose coffee, V8, and 5m of yoga.
I propose a 20m nap.
```

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js skips over code in the switch statement **until it matches *one* case**. When it matches a case, it *stops checking against cases* and waterfalls down, executing code until it sees a `break` or a `}`.

For this situation, use if-then.

```
  const numPomodoros = 3; // Or what the db count shows.

  if (numRecoveries % 3 === 0)
    console.log('I propose coffee, V8, and 5m of yoga.');
  if (numRecoveries % 4 === 0)
    console.log('I propose a 20m nap.');
```

Outputs:

```
$ node index.js s
I propose coffee, V8, and 5m of yoga.
```

Comment: yeah the if is better in this situation

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a break instruction. It  will stop the execution of inside the block.
No break means that the code keeps running.
May be you need a default to. If you want a default action "Like unknown value"

```
const numPomodoros = 3; // It checks the # of pomodoros in the db, but I'm setting it to 3 to illustrate the problem.
  switch (0) {
    case numPomodoros % 3:
      console.log('I propose coffee, V8, and 5m of yoga.');
      break;
    case numPomodoros % 4:
      console.log('I propose a 20m nap.');
      break;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't put a break at the end of the case block,all the following case blocks will be executed too.

Also you should put a default case at the end to handle the cases that aren't matched by any of the previous blocks.

This is the working version:

```
  const numPomodoros = 3; // It checks the # of pomodoros in the db, but I'm setting it to 3 to illustrate the problem.
  switch (0) {
    case numPomodoros % 3:
      console.log('I propose coffee, V8, and 5m of yoga.');
      break;
    case numPomodoros % 4:
      console.log('I propose a 20m nap.');
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Default case.");
    break;  
  }
```